# If a function belongs to $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ for every $p$, does it belong to $W^{k,\infty}(\Omega)$?

Tags: sobolev-spaces

If a function belongs to $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ for every $p$, does it belong to $W^{k,\infty}(\Omega)$?

Under what assumptions on the domain is this true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no, and there are no assumptions on the domain that can help you with this. For example, in one dimension the function $\log x$ is in $L^p((0, 1))$ for all $p<\infty$, but is not in $L^\infty((0, 1))$. Integrating it $k$ times yields an example in $W^{k, p}((0, 1))$; or simpler yet, consider $x^k \log x$.

There are interesting function spaces in between $\bigcap_{p<\infty} W^{k, p}$ and $W^{k, \infty}$:

- **Orlicz-Sobolev spaces**  $W^{k, \Phi}$: replace the integrability of $p$th power of $|D^k u|$ with the integrability of $\Phi(|D^ku|)$ for some Orlicz function $\Phi$ such as $\Phi(t) = e^t$.
- **BMO-Sobolev spaces**, defined by the requirement that $D^k$ has [*bounded mean oscillation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_mean_oscillation).
- **Grand Sobolev spaces**: require a bound on $\|D^k\|_p$ of the form $O(p)$ as $p\to\infty$.

Comment: One could mention that $u \in W^{k,\infty}(\Omega)$ follows if $\| u \|_{W^{k,p}(\Omega)}$ is bounded for $p \to \infty$.